# Convert nested lists to multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lst = [['111', 'kam'],['222', 'Van']]
Header = ['ID', 'Name']
```

I want to convert the above list to dictionary based on the Headers. I can do this simply using for loop by taking each element in loop and append to some new list one by one.

But, I want to achieve the same without using loop to prevent from performance issue.
Is there any way to do that?

Expected Output:

```
[{'ID' : '111', 'Name' : 'Kam'},{'ID' : '222', 'Name' : 'Van'}]
```

Comment: Who said loops have performance issues ?

Comment: My main list will contain 500s of lists inside. I thought, it will take more time to execute. Isn't it?

Comment: list comprehensions are generally faster but they will still include a loop, the difference is you dont need to call the append method of a list over and over again so you get perforamce gain from that

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will try that.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
lst = [['111', 'kam'],['222', 'Van']]
Header = ['ID', 'Name']

result = [dict(zip(Header, row)) for row in lst]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'ID': '111', 'Name': 'kam'}, {'ID': '222', 'Name': 'Van'}]
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.